# How to change Ion-Icon with onclick?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

My aim is to change a (+) Icon to a (-) Icon with a click of a button. I've read other posts but couldn't find an answer using JS. How would I be able to replace an icon with just a click of a button?

```
<ion-button onclick = "favourite()"><ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
```

My function has nothing inside it as I have no clue of how to do it.

Hope I was clear enough. Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: What framework are you using? Angular? React? Vue? or just vanilla JS?

Comment: I am using Vanilla JS.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it worked! Just as a note I had to change the name 'minus-outline' to 'remove-outline' for it to work, just in case someone else tries it. Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `this` reference in the function argument so your function will know which element was clicked.

```
<ion-button onclick = "favourite(this)"><ion-icon name="add-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
```

Then in your js file

```
function favourite(el) {
 el.querySelector('ion-icon').setAttribute('name', 'minus-outline');
}
```

This is saying "*starting at the element that was clicked (el) find the first element with the tag name `ion-icon` and change it's attribute `name` to 'minus-outline'*"

I don't have a way of testing this, so let me know if it works.